# How can i get the name and status of a logic app with the Get-AzResource?

Tags: azure, powershell

I used to get the state of my logic app from the details returned using

```
az resource show  --name 'logicappname' -g 'resourcegroup' --resource-type 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows'
```

The details returned using

```
Get-AzResource -Name logicappname -ResourceGroupName resourcegroup -ResourceType    Microsoft.Logic/workflows
```

does not have the state of the logic app (running or stopped)

How can I get the state and name of the logic app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try doing this:

```
$logicApp = Get-AzResource -Name logicappname -ResourceGroupName resourcegroup `
    -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows' -ExpandProperties
$logicApp.properties
```